# Can't get iTunes music library to replicate on iPhone 6+

Tags: iphone, itunes, data-synchronization

Have researched this and no fixes have helped.  I have songs on my iPhone 6+ that I do not want on it, and I have completely deleted those songs from my iTunes music library.  So when I then sync iTunes to my iPhone, those unwanted songs still remain on my iPhone. Shouldn't the syncing effectively "overwrite" the library that's on my iPhone?  (this is also happening with my iPad) Appreciate suggestions - thanks!

Comment: You can selectively delete songs by going to `Settings → General → iPhone Storage → Music`.

Answer (score 1):

Syncing doesn't actually overwrite the iPhone music library, for whatever reason. Try turning Music sync off entirely (plug-in iPhone, select it in iTunes, go to the Music tab and uncheck the main box), sync, and then turn it back on and sync again. This should cause all of the unwanted songs to be removed.

Comment: Thanks... so when I re-sync the second time, should I have "entire music library" checked or "selected playlists" checked?  I have the latter checked, but something tells me it should be the former.  Thanks!

Comment: The second time you sync, you can make whatever selections you want. If you want all of your iTunes music on your iPhone, select the former. The important part is that it is turned off entirely for one successful sync, to cause it to remove all existing music on the device.

Comment: this is going to work!  Very grateful.  OK - last question, please (hope) - there's an option in iTunes for "include voice memos" on the sync.  I have a recording in the "Voice Memos" app that I made today that I can't afford to lose.  I want to make sure I select the correct option so that it doesn't get overwritten during this process?  (I haven't done the final "re-sync" yet but I can tell that it's going to work because the # of songs is correct in the "Entire Music Library" count that I want to sync to my phone...

Comment: There should be either a Voice Memo section in your iTunes Library or a Voice Memo genre within Music. Either way, it should already be in your library. Right-click on it and choose View in Finder, then copy that file somewhere safe before proceeding.

Comment: (If you choose to sync your entire music library, it should be synced back to the device, but just in case.)

Comment: It doesn't give me the "View Finder" option but as I see it on both my phone and in iTunes, it shouldn't get lost in the shuffle (hope!) - I'm keeping you on retainer!  Many, many thanks for cutting through the clutter that was on any other attempts from others to answer this question!  Greatly appreciated.